# Change keyword TYPE to ENGINE in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this error when importing a database on my phpMyAdmin and from research the solution is to change the keyword TYPE to ENGINE. TYPE has been updated to ENGINE.

How can I make the changes on phpMyAdmin?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wpf8_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `comment_id` (`comment_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) TYPE=MyISAM  AUTO_INCREMENT=96 ;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM  AUTO_INCREMENT=96' at line 19
```

Answer (score 1):

TYPE was deprecated in MySQL 4.0 and removed in MySQL 5.5. When upgrading to MySQL 5.5 or later, you must convert existing applications that rely on TYPE to use ENGINE instead.

You can see the current version of the documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

MySQL 4.0 was released sometime in 2003-2004 and if your version of phpmyadmin uses it, it is extremely old. Update phpmyadmin to the current version and it will solve your issue.